# Trying to understand math behind "Checking whether a coin is fair"

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I would like to understand the standard math done to check whether a coin is fair.

[There is a wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair), and it outlines two different ways of answering the question using a Baysian and Frequentist approach.

I would like to understand the Frequentist approach, which calculates an "estimator of true probability."

To quote wikipedia:

> The best estimator for the actual value r is the estimator
> $p\,\!={\frac {h}{h+t}}.$ This estimator has a margin of error (E)
> where $|p-r|<E$ at a particular confidence level.

What does this mean? How do we know that this is the case?

[One answerer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530329/test-to-determine-whether-coin-is-fair-or-not) in this question does the math with the following formula:

> The formula to calculate the approximate confidence limits for a
> binomial test is: $z_{a l p h a
> > / 2}  \sqrt{p q / n}$

How do I find this formula and how is it related to the "best estimator for r"?

In general, I have a rough understanding of central limit theorem, so I get that some kind of normal distribution might pop up if I start looking at a combination of bunch of trials of independent random distributions, but I would like to understand the mathematical derivation for this "estimator" for determining if a coin is fair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a simple example. Suppose you want to know whether a coin is fair; that is $p = P(Head) = 1/2.$ You toss the coin $n = 50% times and get
$x = 28$ Heads.

Then the *point estimate* for $p$ is $\hat p = x/n = 28/50 = 0.56.$
Various styles of confidence intervals can be used to give an idea how far
from $0.56$ the actual value of $p$ might be.

**Confidence intervals.** One of these is a 95% confidence interval (CI) of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac {\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n} },$ which computes to $(0.422, 0.698).$ [Computation below, using R as a calculator.] Over many such experiments, this style of CI
will include the true Heads probability $p$ of the coin about 95% of the time.
The expression `qnorm(c(.025,.975))` amounts to $\pm 1.96$ and is based on
a normal approximation to the binomial distribution of $X.$ [Wald CI; see Addendum.]

```
x = 28;  n = 50;  p.hat = x/n
CI = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
CI
[1] 0.4224111 0.6975889
```

Experience has shown that a slightly different style of CI (due to Agresti and Coull) comes closer to the 95% goal than the one above. It gives the 95% CI $(0.423, 0.688).$ [Sometimes shorter than the Wald CI, sometimes longer, but with greater precision attuned to the circumstances.]

```
x = 28;  n = 50;  p.est = (x+2)/(n+4)
CI = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/(n+4))
[1] 0.4230227 0.6880885
```

Notice that both styles give intervals that contain $p = 0.5.$ So
data $x = 28, n = 50$ with $\hat p = 0.56$ seems compatible with a fair coin.
(However, with $x = 2792$ heads out of $n = 5000$ tosses, the CI's would
***not*** contain $p = 0.5.$ With such experiments, it is not just the *proportion*
of heads that matters, but also the total *number* of tosses.)

**Test of hypothesis.** Another possibility is to test the null hypothesis $H_0: p=1/2$ against
the alternative $H_a: p\ne 1/2,$ at the 5% level of significance.
There are several versions of this test, some using exact binomial
distributions and some using normal approximations. In R, an exact
test is implemented as `binom.test`, illustrated for data $x = 28, n = 50$ from above. The P-value $0.4799$ tells us that a fair coin would give a result
as far $28 - 25 = 3$ from the expected number of heads almost half the time.
So 28 heads in 50 tosses would not be an unusual result for a fair coin.

```
binom.test(x = 28, n = 50, p = 0.5)

        Exact binomial test

data:  28 and 50
number of successes = 28, number of trials = 50, p-value = 0.4799
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4125441 0.7000928
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.56
```

Here is how the P-value $0.4799$ is computed: If $H_0$ is true then
the observed number of Heads is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=50,p-0.5).$
The P-value is the probability that $X$ is farther from $E(X) = np = 25$
that what we observed. That is, $P(X \le 22)+P(X\ge 28) =$ $2(0.23994) = 0.4799.$

```
pbinom(22, 50, .5)
[1] 0.2399438
1 - pbinom(27, 50, .5)
[1] 0.2399438
```

*One more style of CI:* Notice that the 95% CI from this procedure is $(0.413, 0.700),$ based on
yet another style of confidence interval (Clopper-Pearson CI). [About half a dozen styles are
in common use. For more about this [see this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).]

Finally, if I had as many as $x=2792$ heads out of $n=5000$ tosses, then the
P-value would be much smaller than $0.05 = 5\%$ and we would reject $H_0$
at the 5% level of significance. And the 95% CI would be  $(0.545, 0.572),$
which does not contain $p = 0.5.$

Just from your question, I am not sure what aspects of the coin-testing problem
interest you most. If there are parts of the above that don't make sense to
you, or other topics of interest that I omitted, then you can ask questions
in comments or post a more specific Question. Also, the margin of this question has links to 'Related' Q&A's on this site that may be of interest.

**Addendum** per comment. Argument for the Wald CI (which was originally intended only for very large $n.)$

Begin with $E(\hat p) = p; SE = SD(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$ Assuming $\hat p$ is normal, standardize to get $Z = \frac{\hat p - p}{SE} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ so that $P(-1.96 < Z < 1.96)\approx 0.95.$ Use algebra to transform the event, obtaining
$P(\hat p - 1.96SE < p < \hat p + 1.96SE)\approx 0.95.$ Then ***provided we knew SE***, an approximate 95% CI for $p$ would be of the form
$(\hat p - 1.96SE,\, \hat p + 1.96SE).$ However $SE = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ contains ***unknown*** $p.$ For sufficiently large $n,$ one has $\hat p \approx p,$ so approximate $SE$ as $\widehat{SE} = \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$ Then pretend $\left(\hat p - 1.96\widehat{SE},\, \hat p + 1.96\widehat{SE}\right)$ is 95% CI for $p.$

Comment: thanks for the write-up. I am still struggling to understand the derivation of the [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). Is there a straightforward way to arrive at $\hat{p} \pm z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$?

Comment: Tried to show that in Comment beneath your Q, Will try again in Addendum. A difficulty is that there are many approximations.

Comment: even a reference resource is good, ideally one with the derivation and doesnt require reading an entire textbook.

Comment: Addendum is finished. Deleting comment after your Question.

Comment: I learnt from this answer. The Wikipedia link says “[t]he Normal approximation interval and its presentation in textbooks has been heavily criticised, with many statisticians advocating that it be not used. The principal problems are overshoot (bounds exceed [0, 1]), zero-width intervals at ${\hat {p}} = 0$ and $1$ (falsely implying certainty), and overall inconsistency with significance testing.” So the other methods you mention may be better for actual data anaysis.

Comment: Yes, Others are better. Agresti-Coull, using $\hat p = (x+2)/(n+4)$ is noticeably better. Exact method implemented in R's `binom.test` gives wider intervals (sometimes unnecessarily wide), but true 95% coverage. See my Wikipedia link for discussion/formulas of several types. // Simple to use in R and surprisingly good is to take quantiles $.025$ and $.975$ of $\mathsf{Beta}(x+.5, n-x+.5),$ which gives $(0.422, 0.690)$ for my example with $x=28, n=50.$ [Jeffries CI.]

Comment: @BruceET, Thanks for the explanation. I'm still conceptually confused - as I get lost conceptually in your derivation. I wrote a new question about it to hopefully make that more clear. [which is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530789/struggling-to-understand-what-a-confidence-interval-is-in-problem-involving-m)