# Struggling to understand what a "confidence interval" is (In problem involving multiple coinflips)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Following [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530454/trying-to-understand-math-behind-checking-whether-a-coin-is-fair), I am trying to learn the math behind checking whether a coin is fair.

While user @BruceET provides an outline of the overall math to get there, I am still stuck on the basic concepts, which I have pinned down to not understand the "Binomial proportion confidence interval."

In his answer he writes:

> **Addendum** per comment. Argument for the Wald CI (which was originally intended only for very large $n.)$
> Begin with $E(\hat p) = p; SE = SD(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$
> Assuming $\hat p$ is normal, standardize to get $Z = \frac{\hat p -
> > p}{SE} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ so that $P(-1.96 < Z
> > < 1.96)\approx 0.95.$ Use algebra to transform the event, obtaining
> $P(\hat p - 1.96SE < p < \hat p + 1.96SE)\approx 0.95.$ Then
> ***provided we knew SE***, an approximate 95% CI for $p$ would be of the form $(\hat p - 1.96SE,\, \hat p + 1.96SE).$ However $SE =
> > \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ contains ***unknown*** $p.$ For sufficiently
> large $n,$ one has $\hat p \approx p,$ so approximate $SE$ as
> $\widehat{SE} = \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$ Then pretend
> $\left(\hat p - 1.96\widehat{SE},\, \hat p + 1.96\widehat{SE}\right)$
> is 95% CI for $p.$

So from this [question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89154/general-method-for-deriving-the-standard-error), I think I understand the first step. To quote the answer:

> So, let the items that you pick be represented by the random variables
> $X_i, 1\le i \le n$, each of them identically distributed with
> variance $\sigma^2$. They are independently sampled, so the variance
> of the sum is just the sum of the variances. $$
> > \text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) =
> > \sum_{i=1}^n\text{Var}\left(X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2 =
> > n\sigma^2 $$
>
> Next we divide by $n$. We know in general that $\text{Var}(kY)=k^2
> > \text{Var}(Y)$, so putting $k=1/n$ we have
>
> $$ \text{Var}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}
> > \text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} n\sigma^2 =
> > \frac{\sigma^2}{n} $$
>
> Finally take the square root to get the standard deviation
> $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. When the population standard deviation
> isn't available the sample standard deviation $s$ is used as an
> estimate, giving $\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$.

So if I make a random variable that represents the average value of a bunch of coin flips (where heads is assigned a 1 and occurs with probability p; tails is assigned a 0 and occurs with probability q=1-p), then the expected value of that random value for n coinflips is n*p and the standard deviation is $\dfrac{\sigma_c}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $\sigma_c$ is the standard deviation of flipping a single coin (which is p(1-p)).

So now for any number of coins, I know the expected value of how many will flip heads. I can also now know the frequency of heads vs tails represented as a number from 0-to-1 by dividing by the total amount of flips, which is represented by $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n E\left(X_i\right)}{n}$. I have also now calculated the variance of this random variable.

Now from what I understand from @BruceETs explanation of the "Binomial proportion confidence interval", we can use this information to estimate our distribution for this random variable as a normal distribution. We find a section that has 95% of the area under this normal distribution that we estimate to be centered around the frequency of heads that we measured $\hat{p} = N_{Heads}/N_{Total}$.

And it's around this point that I am conceptually lost. The goal is to get an estimate for the probability of the weighted coin. So in this case does confidence interval of 95% represent the following: "95% of the time a fair coin would observe this"?

**I am really struggling to interpret what this confidence interval exactly represents. My goal is to be able to quantify exactly what my "confidence" is in a certain weighted parameter. So for example if I perform 100 different tests of flipping 1000 fair coins, how often will my 95% CI test fail? Is it expected to fail 5% of the time?**

Ideally an answer that connects to the details of the math for the "Binomial proportion confidence interval" would be preferred. (I think I understand conceptually that there are some definition problems with assigning a probability weight as a random distribution when it is predetermined, as answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/what-precisely-is-a-confidence-interval). My question is more about just trying to actually understand how this confidence interval is generated and how the math actually explains what it is.)